# Trying to submit stringified text to server as property of an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following instructions:

- To submit a new chat message, you'll need to send a POST request to a RESTful resource endpoint on the Parse API. The url for that resource is https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats.
- The endpoint is expecting to get an object from you that contains a property named "text" (and no other properties).
- NOTE: The Parse API expects the message data object you send to be encoded as JSON, so you'll want to stringify it that way before POSTing it.

I've created the following function but it doesn't seem to be working. When I fetch the text I submit, it just reads as "undefined". Any tips? Thanks so much!

```
var input1 = document.getElementById('input1'), sendbutton = document.getElementById('sendbutton');

function chatSend(){

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats",
           data: JSON.stringify({text: $('input1.draft').val()}), 

           success:function(message){


           }
      })
    }
```

my html is setup as follows

```
<input class="draft" name="input1" id="input1" type="text" value=''/>
```

Comment: guess its a simple typo, use $('input instead of $('input1.

Comment: i just tried 'input1' instead of 'input1.draft' but it didn't seem to help. Any other ideas?

Comment: so my mistake, i didn't read your comment carefully. input works!

Comment: can you explain why though? I don't define input anywhere, only input1

Comment: it is a class selector, you have an input with class draft. investigate jquery selectors if this comes unfamiliar.